# add root directory as include directory

Tags: c++, cmake

During compilation certain header files aren't found, although I added the respective include directories in CMake. Unfortunately this is the code and directory structure I am stuck with and I can't change anything on the include statements.

I have the following directory structure:

```
projectfolder
+--source1
|  |--prog.cpp
|  |--anotherHeader.h
|  |--CMakeLists
|
+--includefolder
|  +--source1_include
|  |  |--header.h
|  
|--CMakeLists
```

CMakeLists in projectfolder looks like this:

```
project (project)
include_directories(includefolder)
add_subdirectory(source1)
```

prog.cpp has:

```
#include  "source1_include/header.h"
```

and header.h has:

```
 #include  "anotherHeader.h"
```

(don't ask me why, I don't know myself, maybe it has something to do with the fact that originally this is a Visual Studio project)

I thought I could fix this, by adding

```
include_directories(.)
```

to the CMakeLists in the source1 directory but unfortunately it wont work that way. anotherHeader.h isn't found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that "." is "projectfolder"

If I understand correctly, you added -I "projectfolder", so now "source1_include/header.h" correctly finds "projectfolder/source1_include/header.h"

Now, "header.h" tries to include "anotherHeader.h", which is not in its folder and not in any of the included folders. It is actually in "source1". So cmake is correct to error out.

You need to either move "anotherHeader.h" into your includes folder (my recommendation), or edit "header.h" to find it by the correct relative path "../source1/anotherHeader.h" (not recommended), or add include_directories("source1"), which is where it actually is.